# Mostrar un alert() despues de enviar un formulario

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo una página a la que llamaremos `pagina.php` con un formulario. Al hacer `submit` envío el formulario con `<form method="post" action="validar_datos.php">`. Entonces `validar_datos.php` comprueba que los datos introducidos en el formulario sean correctos y si lo son los envía a la base de datos. Independientemente, de que los datos sean correctos o no, al finalizar la comprobación redirijo al usuario a la página del formulario mediante `header('location:pagina.php?r=1')` si los datos son correctos o `header('location:pagina.php?r=0')` si los datos NO son correctos.

Dentro de `pagina.php` tengo el siguiente script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['r'] == 1)){
    echo '<div id="message"><p>Nuevo cliente añadido con éxito!</p></div>
    <script>$("#message").delay(1500).fadeOut(200);</script>'; 
}else if($_GET['r'] == 0)){
    echo '<div id="message"><p>Datos incorrectos</p></div>
    <script>$("#message").delay(1500).fadeOut(200);</script>'; 
}else{
}
?>
```

Es decir, muestro un mensaje de "éxito" si el índice `r` pasado por la URL es 1 o un mensaje de "error" si el índice `r` es 0.

Cuando el usuario esté, por ejemplo, en la página `pagina.php?r=1` si vuelve a recargar la página le saldrá otra vez el mensaje de "éxito" y así todas las veces que refresque la página. Incluso podría modificar el valor de `r` de la URL por 0 y le saldría el mensaje de "error".

Mi pregunta es:
Como actualmente uso `header('location:pagina.php?r=valor')` para redirigir al usuario, hay algún modo de hacerlo pasando el índice `r` y su valor de forma totalmente invisible para que el usuario no lo pudiera modificar? 
Y se podría hacer que solamente se mostrase el mensaje una vez independientemente de las veces que se refresque la página?

Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Hola, buen día, lo mas optimo seria que usaras ajax para realizar tu proceso, asi podrás realizar tu proceso y en base al retorno del ajax, y si necesitas redireccionar, tambien prodras hacerlo ó tambien podrias almacenar el valor de la variable $_GET['r'] en una variable de sessión

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu formulario agrega

```
<form action="/pagina.php" method="post">
```

Dentro de tu formulario puedes tener un input oculto

```
<input type="hidden" name="r" id="r" value="">
```

Y cuando hagas click en el formulario para hacer `submit`

```
<script>
    var r = document.getElementById("r"); 
    //Tus validaciones para saber si los datos son correctos o no....
    r.value = 1 //o 0, dependiendo de tu validacion
    r.element.form.submit();
</script>
```

Tambien una muy buena opcion es utilizar ajax

```
$.post('pagina.php', {r : r});
```

Y el valor recibelo como `$_POST['r']` en tu archivo PHP

**EDICION**

Respecto a que explicas bien como era tu problema. En mi opinión es el flujo el que tiene cierto problema. En un archivo tu VALIDAS los campos y en otro envías un mensaje de error o éxito. Me parece que en el archivo de validación deberías enviar el mensaje de alerta ahorrándote volver a redirigir.

Comment: el formulario ya lo tengo con method='post'. Cuando envío el formulario obtengo los valores y luego redirijo al usuario usando header('location:pagina.php?r=valor') siendo 'valor' un 1 o 0 dependiendo de si los datos son correctos o no. Entonces el usuario es redirigido a `localhost/pagina.php?r=1` y dento de pagina.php compruebo el valor del índice r y muestro un mensaje u otro. No se si me explico bien

Comment: Por eso, con mi respuesta deberias sacar el `header('location:pagina.php?r=valor') ` ya que no necesitamos que regirija de esa manera, solo en el POST del formulario, con el codigo javascript obtienes el valor y luego haces el submit, esto hara lo mismo que necesitas tu

Comment: he editado al pregunta porque creo que no explicaba correctamente mi problema

Comment: tu rediriges a una pagina a la cual haces post y DENTRO de esa pagina nuevamente rediriges con el parametro r? es eso?

Comment: sí, es decir, la página a la que hago el post es `validar_datos.php` y es solo script php y cuando se ejecuta este script redirijo al usuario a la página anterior mostrando un mensaje de "exito" o de "error"

Comment: @gmarsi puedes agregar el codigo de validar_datos ???